# Which user-account should a windows service run under on WIndows 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-services, windows-server-2012, user-permissions

I am trying to move a service from my local PC that connects to local servers at the company to a 3rd party dedicated server with SQL/Windows 2012.

It has been like knocking nails in my head getting as far as I have and at the moment the service runs if I log into the computer as root and open the service control and give it "local system account" privileges to run (and ability to interface with desktop - I have a stop/start Win Form that gives me info on the 3rd party API it connects to)- it runs.

That is it runs, except when it tries connect to the localhost database it needs to it bombs out with an exception of: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server);

However if I run a .NET program I wrote to give me details about a machine (e.g drives, users and log on times, ability to send an email with localhost, obtain the servers IP from an outside HTTP request) and connect to the localhost SQL Server and with the same connection string (DB, User, PSW) as my service then it can connect and extract information about the SQL users in the sys views and collation differences.

This is a console app I run in a command prompt as  when I log into the box as root but I don't have to open the command prompt as admin as most other apps require to get these details back and connect to the same SQL DB.

If I just try and change the service to use "existing account" OR enter in the root user / psw into the boxes and try the service doesn't even get as far as starting with a "Windows could not start the xx service on the local computer" and in the event viewer it is just an unhandled .NET exception which seems like it couldn't for some reason (permissions - why when it was root?) erroring logging to the event log I have created for it.

Application: BrainiacV2.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.ArgumentException at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType, Int32, Int16, Byte[]) at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType) at BrainiacV2.BrainiacJobs.WriteToEventLog(System.Exception, System.String)

These errors are only happening on the combined Windows 2012/SQL server not my Win7 PC and remote DB server.

I did read this article as well as many others that said the local user account should be enough to get it running.

[what Windows account should a service run under to access network sql servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338773/what-windows-account-should-a-service-run-under-to-access-network-sql-servers)

Any advice on debugging this when all the core code is within a DLL the service uses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to follow, but I'll try.

There is no "root" on Windows unless someone created an account with that name.

> I have a stop/start Win Form

You can't have a form in a Windows Service. It doesn't get a desktop and isn't allowed.

> and give it "local system account" privileges to run  . . . I have a stop/start Win Form that gives me info on the 3rd party API it connects to)- it runs.

The LocalSystem account is restricted to the machine it's running on. It doesn't have network privileges. If your database is on another machine, you won't be able to connect to it. The solution is to have the service run as a user with the correct permissions.

> (and ability to interface with desktop -

This doesn't work in later versions of Windows and even when it does work is unreliable and unpredictable.

> provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server);

This means that the Named Pipes provider was not configured on SQL Server and you're trying to use it. You can either configure it, or switch your connection to a provider that actually is configured in SQL Server. It's also possible that the server isn't reachable using the name you specified. Can you ping it using the name you specified?

The last message indicates that you have no top level try/catch block, which means that errors are fatal. You need to catch and handle them, especially in a service.

If you can make your question more understandable and narrow down the exact problem you're having, I can probably give you more help.

Comment: Admin gave me root as my main user login. All errors I Know about are not fatal news one not handled as need full trace to fix. Mayb its the copy from  from Win7 to Win2012. It runs on my boxes local account and can access SQL and outside world. You can easily make Win APP forms that sit in the desktray and can hook into Servcice. It lets me stop/start & tells me if 3rd party API is up & running so its useful desk app. So works fine in that format on my PC just getting it to OVH is prob - and now I think its French IP (French IPS) being blocked by the 3rd party API. I can ping,